# React: How to download image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In the project, I am trying to download an image.

action.tsx

```
const handleClick = () => {
    if (tab == "link") {
      copyToClipboard();
    } else if (tab == "Code") {
      <a href={image} download>
      </a>;
    }
  };

....
....
   <Button
       className={`primary-button ${styles.button}`}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            {tab === "email"
              ? "Send Email"
              : tab === "link"
              ? "Copy Link"
              : tab === "Code"
              ? "Download QR Code"
              : "Copy Frame"}
    </Button>
```

when the tab = code then the button functionality is changed to "download image", For that
added anchor tag. When I console the "image", it shows the image URL, but the download not working. Please give me some suggestions to fix this situation.

Comment: Is your issue only with images, or you are unable to create a link to download any type of file?

Comment: The image field only has image files, when I console the "image" value, url is there but "<a href={image} download" is not working.